# Script is not launched on startup

Tags: linux, ubuntu

This is my `bot1.conf` file in `/etc/init`:

```
start on startup
task
exec /bot/start.sh
```

This is `start.sh`:

```
#! while true; do nohup java -jar /bot/bot.jar & && break; done
```

When the server reboots, it doesn't launch the `bot.jar` automatically.

I want this java application to be launched if any exception occurred or if the system was rebooted.

Comment: your ```.sh``` file are executable? ```chmod +x /bot/start.sh```

Comment: Yes. I tried to avoid nohup, even this didn't help